# How to change Magento default admin language

Tags: magento

I have Magento 1.7.0.2 German website. How can i change the admin panel to be English by default? (i know that i can select the language from the drop down list, however i want it to be set to English by default)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In top menu

system > config > (general) general > locale options > locale > english (US)
be sure to set that at the "default config" scope, and log out and then in to be taken into account

Comment: Hi! Thank you too much .I have been facing this problem since yesterday!

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, but that option changed some labels in the frontend too... Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, this solution also affects the front-end. See my answer for an extension that allows to set a default language per admin account.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah yes, obviously, but you can change frontend's locale at store or store view level

Answer (score 8):

In General, if you want a shop frontend default language that differs from the admin default language, the easiest way is:

Set Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Locale

- For Default Config: admin language (English)
- For Website Level: frontend language (German)

Then, on store level, you can still have other (partly translated) locales that would have the website level language as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps and you will get what you want:

1. In your Magento admin go to System > Manage Stores
2. Click  on Main Website Store  under the Store Name (if there are several  ones, click any of them)
3. On the next page under Store Information select a different language in the Default Store View drop-down list.
4. Click Save Store.
5. Now every time you are opening the your site, it’s going to be in the language  you selected.
6. You can change the default  language for the backend by going to System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale options.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed in the other answer also affects the front-end, so it might not be ideal for some scenarios: For example if you have multiple stores in the front-end and their default language should be English, you might not want to set the default locale to anything other than English.

I found [Aoe_BackendDefaultLanguage](https://github.com/zohmi/Aoe_BackendDefaultLanguage) extension on GitHub that allows to set a default language per admin account. It seems to be working good so far and the code seems quite clean.

Comment: your statement "<i>For example if you have multiple stores in the front-end and their default language should be English, the default locale can't be set to anything other than English.</i>" is wrong: you can determine the locale for every store/store view independently of the default locale

Comment: Yes, you can, but in some cases it might not be suitable. We have 30+ stores and just a few of them use non-english languages. So we want to leave English as the the default language. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @LouisBataillard Extension is working here, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I found a small dropdown window in the bottom left corner of the default admin window that allowed me to change this. I managed to fix it... not an easy thing to find.

[Change language in Magento 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anvP9.png)